# IS-IS Hello packets and IPv4/IPv6 addresses

Tags: is-is

IS-IS Hello packets contain IPv4(and IPv6 address). For example see the "IPv4 Interface" field in this IS-IS Hello packet:

```
$ tcpdump -c1 -vvvr isis.pcap
reading from file isis.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
12:59:55.406559 IS-IS, length 81
        L2 Lan IIH, hlen: 27, v: 1, pdu-v: 1, sys-id-len: 6 (0), max-area: 3 (0)
        0x0000:  831b 0100 1001 0000
          source-id: 0101.2812.3087,  holding time: 9s, Flags: [Level 2 only]
          lan-id:    0101.2812.3087.02, Priority: 64, PDU length: 81
          0x0000:  0206 2128 1230 8700 0900 5140 0101 2812
          0x0010:  3087 02
            IS Neighbor(s) TLV #6, length: 12
              SNPA: dead.beef.6905
              SNPA: dead.beef.6906
              0x0000:  dead beef 6905 dead beef 6906
            Protocols supported TLV #129, length: 2
              NLPID(s): IPv4 (0xcc), IPv6 (0x8e)
              0x0000:  cc8e
            IPv4 Interface address(es) TLV #132, length: 4
              IPv4 interface address: 10.128.123.87
              0x0000:  3e80 7b57
            Area address(es) TLV #1, length: 4
              Area address (length: 3): 49.0233
              0x0000:  0349 0233
            Restart Signaling TLV #211, length: 3
              Flags [none], Remaining holding time 0s
              0x0000:  0000 00
            Authentication TLV #10, length: 17
              HMAC-MD5 password: 67cb4d674c12c0df8bb1b1ad06788c46 (unchecked)
              0x0000:  3600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
              0x0010:  00
$
```

In addition, both Cisco and Juniper routers show the adjacent router IPv4/IPv6 address in `show isis adjacency detail`/`sh isis neighbors` output. Am I correct that this IPv4/IPv6 address **always** belongs to the interface where the IS-IS PDU was sent out? Is this specified in some standard? Why is the interface IPv4/IPv6 address included to IS-IS Hello packet?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In essence - take a look at [RFC 1195](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1195), section 5.1:

```
IP Interface Address -- the IP address(es) of the interface
corresponding to the SNPA over which this PDU is to be transmitted.
```

Why IP needs to be there? Remember that IS-IS is L2 protocol and L3 information (IPv4 or IPv6 address information) is overlay information for IS-IS. It's not needed for IS-IS itself, but needed to manage neighbourship at the L3 level for given IPv4 or IPv6 routing nodes.

Answer (score 2):

It is typically the IP address tied to the physical interface, but not always.  JunOS from Juniper, for example, sends the Router-ID which can be a loopback and not tied to a physical address.

Source:
https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25145&actp=search